# Use git archive from a subdirectory to archive whole project tree

Tags: git, testing, version-control, tar

I'm tired of saying `(cd ../../.. && git archive HEAD) | (cd /var/www/html/ && tar xf -) #testing-on-prod`. Is there a way to cut out the initial `cd`, specifying that I want the whole tree archived and not just the current working directory?

Comment: You can open git bash in any directory (as the example https://ibb.co/fDUe6y) you need to execute the git command.

Comment: I experimented a bit and found you can archive a subdirectory but cannot archive an upper directory. `cd` seems to be the only way.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT I'm not using "git bash" (AKA Git Bash for Windows). Stop spamming SE to promote your company's products. If every question about git had 20 comments each advocating a different git helper tool or OS, no useful discussion could take place.

Comment: @phd Ah, yes I had come across information about archiving a subdirectory. Great to know it's not just me that can't apply it to the top level. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a shortcut function in .bashrc ?

```
<shortcut_name> () { cd <path> ; <other command> ; }
```

Comment: I *think* there's a way to do this with a Git command - I seem to remember doing it a few months ago. Not 100% sure. Thanks for the suggestion though - useful if I'm mistaken (which I likely am).